# Souriau method for Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, polynomial-math, numerical-analysis

Does anyone know the Souriau method for ﬁnding the characteristic polynomial of any n × n matrix? I found out the first coefficient, is obvious, but how can I find out the other coefficients? After I need to inverse the matrix but I know how.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

double trace(double a[5][5],int n){ 
        int i;
        double trace=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
            trace+=a[i][i]; 
        return trace;
}
double prod(double a[5][5],double b[5][5],int n) {
    double c[5][5];
    int i,j,k;
    cout << "\nProd:\n"; 
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){ 
        for(j=0;j<n;++j){ 
            c[i][j]=0; 
            for(k=0;k<n;++k) 
                c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][k]*b[k][j]);
                cout << c[i][j] << " "; 
        } 
        cout << "\n"; 
    } 
    return c[i][j]; 
}
double theta(double a[5][5], int n){
    int i;
    double theta[5];
    theta[1]=-trace(a,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << "Theta[" << i+1 << "]=" << theta[i+1] << "\n";
    return theta[i+1];
}

int main(){ 
    ifstream f("a.txt"); 
    ifstream g("b.txt");
    double a[5][5],b[5][5];
    int i,j,n; 
    f >> n; 
    g >> n; 
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) 
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) 
            f >> a[i][j]; 
    cout << "Matrix A:"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) 
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) 
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) 
            g >> b[i][j]; 
    cout << "Matrix B:" << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){ 
        for(j=0;j<n;++j) 
            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
    }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Trace = ";
        cout << trace(a,n);
        cout << endl;
        prod(a,b,n);
        cout << endl;
        theta(a,n);
    }
```

Comment: So? What is your code-related question? What does the code you posted do? What problem do you have with this code?

Comment: I need to find out all the theta (polynomial coefficients) and I don't know how to do it, this code should find the coefficients and in the end to do the inverse of the matrix A. Is called the Souriau method. The problem in my code is that I don't know how to calculate theta.

Comment: You might find more references if you look for the Leverrier-Faddeev method. See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/a/405975/115115

Comment: Invented and re-discovered by Urbain Le Verrier - 1840, Dmitri K. Faddeev - 1949, J. S. Frame  - 1949, Jean-Marie Souriau - 1948, also U. Wegner - 1953 and L. Csanky - 1973

Comment: Instead of trying to do low-level coding yourself, which is very error prone, I suggest you use some matrix computation library. GSL, for example, is very stable but has only a C API. Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) with a native C++ API is also a very good choice.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot, I'm a beginner so I don't know so many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405975/115115 by 
Ｊ. Ｍ.

```
C=A;
for k=1,…,n

    if k>1
        C=A*(C+c[n−k+1]*I);

    c[n−k]=−tr(C)/k;

end for
```

If you can read the german, there is a wiki page with extended pseudo-code algortihm at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmus_von_Faddejew-Leverrier (add 2017: or the equally good english version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm)

If you want to directly compute the inverse matrix, then you have, as in the wiki page, use the matrix B that is related to the matrix C above via C=A*B. This gives, as can be seen in the wiki page, a slightly more complicated algorithm. However, then the last matrix B satisfies A*B=-c[0]*I, so that the inverse matrix, if there is one, can be directly computed.